# Amazon SES breaks CSS and images don't display

Tags: node.js, html-email, serverless, amazon-ses

I want to send HTML emails through Amazon SES like this.
[image]
But what I get is like this.
[image]
And I implemented like below using sendEmail method of the AWS.SES. But the 2 columns CSS breaks using `display: inline-block;` and the images are not displaying using absolute path `src="https://aaa.com/images/woman-with.jpg"` . I tested by PutsMail. And it's no problem with Gmail. But through SES, it's not working. So my code may have some issues. I would be appreciated it if you give me some advice.

- index.js

```
import * as messages from './messages';
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region
AWS.config.update({ region: 'REGION' });

// Create sendEmail params
var params = {
  Destination: {
    /* required */
    CcAddresses: [
      'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
      /* more items */
    ],
    ToAddresses: [
      'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
      /* more items */
    ],
  },
  Message: {
    /* required */
    Body: {
      /* required */
      Html: {
        Charset: 'UTF-8',
        Data: messages.txt,
      },
      Text: {
        Charset: 'UTF-8',
        Data: messages.html,
      },
    },
    Subject: {
      Charset: 'UTF-8',
      Data: 'Test email',
    },
  },
  Source: 'SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS' /* required */,
  ReplyToAddresses: [
    'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
    /* more items */
  ],
};

// Create the promise and SES service object
var sendPromise = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: '2010-12-01' })
  .sendEmail(params)
  .promise();

// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
sendPromise
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data.MessageId);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
  });
```

- messages.js

```
// import SETTINGS from '../../../settings'

export default () => {
  const messages = {
      txt: [
        `先日はご利用いただきありがとうございました。`,
      ].join('\n'),
      html: [
        `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`,
        `<head>`,
        `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`,
        `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`,
        `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`,
        `<title>a</title>`,
        `</head>`,
        `<body style="margin: 0;background-color: #ccc">`,
          `<center class="wrapper" style="width: 100%;table-layout: fixed;background-color: #ccc;padding-bottom: 60px">`,
          `<table class="main" width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;background-color: #fff;margin: 0 auto;width: 100%;max-width: 600px;font-family: sans-serif;color: #171a1b">`,
          `<!-- TWO COLUMN SECTION -->`,
          `<tr>`,
            `<td style="background-color: rgba(0, 128, 96, 1);color: #fff;padding: 0">`,
              `<table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0">`,
                `<tr>`,
                  `<td class="two-columns" style="padding: 0;text-align: center;font-size: 0">`,
                    `<table class="column" style="border-spacing: 0;width: 100%;max-width: 300px;display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;text-align: center">`,
                      `<tr>`,
                        `<td style="padding: 0">`,
                          `<table class="content" style="border-spacing: 0;font-size: 15px;line-height: 20px;text-align: left">`,
                            `<tr>`,
                              `<td style="padding: 0">`,
                                `<img src="https://aaa.com/images/woman-with.jpg" alt="woman-with" title="woman-with" border="0" width="300" height="200"  style="display: block; max-width: 300px;border: 0" />`,
                              `</td>`,
                            `</tr>`,
                          `</table>`,
                        `</td>`,
                      `</tr>`,
                    `</table>`,
                    `<table class="column" style="border-spacing: 0;width: 100%;max-width: 300px;display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;text-align: center">`,
                      `<tr>`,
                        `<td class="padding" style="padding: 20px">`,
                          `<table class="content" style="border-spacing: 0;font-size: 15px;line-height: 20px;text-align: left">`,
                            `<tr>`,
                              `<td style="padding: 0">`,
                                `<p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:18px;">3% オフ</p>`,
                                `<p style="font-size:14px;">レビュー頂くと...</p>`,
                                `<p style="padding-bottom: 14px;">次回のお買い物でご利用いただける3%オフのクーポンをゲット！</p>`,
                              `</td>`,
                            `</tr>`,
                          `</table>`,
                        `</td>`,
                      `</tr>`,
                    `</table>`,
                  `</td>`,
                `</tr>`,
              `</table>`,
            `</td>`,
          `</tr>`,
          `</table>`,
          `</center>`,
        `</body>`,
        `</html>`,
      ].join('<br />'),
    },
  return messages
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-khno3j?embed=1&file=messages.js

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? An error message fails to send it at all? Or it looks weird in Gmail (which Gmail? webmail/app?)

Comment: It looks weird I mean. Images doesn't display and `display: inline-block` is broken.

Comment: Are you able to extract the code that's output? (Steps via Gmail: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33926/can-i-view-the-html-source-of-an-email-sent-to-my-gmail-address)

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't have use `].join('<br />')` at the end.